# Breakout Character in HTTP Headers

Tags: http, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a cyber sec CTF for a school project. I want to put one of the flags in the server header of a website using URL Rewrite for Microsoft IIS. I'm storing my flags in curly braces '{}' but anything put between them seems to be commented out. Is there a breakout character I could use that would allow me to use the characters without them being commented out?

Comment: Did you mean that you will hit a url like "xxx/{flag}/xxx" and want it redirect to the real url?

Comment: Not the url, no. If you do a wget request you can pull up the headers associated with the website. One of them being the server info. I’m trying to change it using Microsoft’s URL rewrite tool, but name aside its not the URL that I’m editing.